# Powershell not getting SharePoint Online List

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to write a script for automatic VM Backups, that you can also start manually in SharePoint Online. I'm planning to keep a list with the names of the VMs in SharePoint and wanted to start writing the script by getting the list of VMs. I think my code looks good so far, but when I want to get the list by title it returns nothing.
Here's the code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client").location))
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime").location))


Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}

Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    return $items 
}

$UserName = read-host "Please enter your name:"
$PasswordReadHost = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$Password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($PasswordReadHost))
$Url = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/"
$ListTitle = "VMList"
$context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$items = Get-ListItems -Context $context -ListTitle $ListTitle
```

When I run this, add a breakpoint at the end and check the value of the `$list` variable I get two error messages:

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The list
>   'VMList' does not exist on the website with the URL
>   'https://domain.sharepoint.com'.

and

> An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The
>   collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the
>   request has not been executed. It  may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

After a lot of googling I tried changing many things, but nothing seemed to work. I guess my question is: Why can't  the list be found on SharePoint and what does it mean to initialize a collection or if it's just an authorization issue?